# Why does a regex match return more than normal in nodejs?

Tags: regex, node.js

If i perform this instruction in the node repl

```
"hello".match(/(\w+)(.*)/)
```

It returns this

```
[ 'hello',
  'hello',
  '',
  index: 0,
  input: 'hello' ]
```

I expected it to return the first three items, where did the other values come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The first item in the array is the entire regex match ("group 0"). That's `hello`, of course.
- The second item is the content of the first capturing group's match `(\w+)`. That's `hello`, again.
- The third item is  the content of the second capturing group's match `(.*)`. That's the empty string after `hello`.
- `index` is the position of the start of the match - which is the first character of the string.
- `input` shows you the string that the regex was performed on - which is `hello`.

It's surprisingly difficult to find docs on this (at least for me), but here's something from MSDN that describes the object returned by a regex match: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7df7sf4x(v=vs.94).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7df7sf4x%28v=vs.94%29.aspx):

> If the global flag is not set, the array returned by the match method has two properties, `input` and `index`. The `input` property contains the entire searched string. The `index` property contains the position of the matched substring within the complete searched string.

Comment: ok, I couldn't figure out why the index and input properties were appearing, I was just expecting the matches.

Comment: MSDN is a jungle... Nice explanation, +1 :)