# Why does a nonglobal match with RegExp return an unexpected array in my environment?

Tags: javascript, regex, search

I am having to complete a exercise in JavaScript where I use RegExp. During testing, I stumbled across this returned array when I did a non global match.

```
var first = "28".match(/[0-9]\s?/);
console.log(first);
```

which returns this array in my terminal:

```
[ '2', index: 0, input: '28' ]
```

(I know an array is expected. But I expected to get `["2"]`.)

Also, I did notice that running a global match did return a expected array.

```
var first = "28".match(/[0-9]/g);
console.log(first);
```

I didn't find any help online when reading .match() documentation. What is causing a global flag to change the returned array so much? I am assuming it is something to do with my environment because that is where I encounter this (as opposed to iframed repl sites like JSBin).

Comment: See [_ECMA Specifications_](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.10)

Comment: I wonder why [Why does a regex match return more than normal in nodejs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414015/why-does-a-regex-match-return-more-than-normal-in-nodejs) refers to MSDN rather than to MDN/WS3 and the accepted answer states it is difficult to find good documentation. It is really easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> If the regular expression does not include the `g` flag, returns the
>   same result as `RegExp.exec()`. The returned Array **has an extra `input`
>   property, which contains the original string that was parsed**. In
>   addition, **it has an `index` property, which represents the zero-based
>   index of the match in the string**.

So, that is why `match` with no `g` returned so many elements. Now:

> If the regular expression includes the `g` flag, the method returns an
>   **Array containing all matched substrings rather than match objects**.
>   Captured groups are not returned. If there were no matches, the method
>   returns null.

Thus, your first element is the first text that matched the regex.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the tip about RegExp.exec() having the same capability. Quick question: is this additional index and input property information being returned not just because I am omitting 'g' but also because I am using node?

Comment: It is only because of the global modifier.