# NodeJS - get substring in between 2 strings, taking first occurrence of the second string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Input:

```
abc/xyz/main/zzz/123/ooo/
```

Want substring between "main/" and the first "/" after that.
Output:

```
"zzz"
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5642329/3832970 post in the linked thread. Use `s.match(/main\/(.*?)\//)[1]`

Comment: I do not want array, but just the single match

Comment: You get it with the above code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414015/why-does-a-regex-match-return-more-than-normal-in-nodejs I get an array with regex, output, index, and input. I think I should always consider the response[1]

Comment: Read [`RegExp#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) reference. It is by design.